# How to use remote machine to remote debug in VisualStudio 2017 with new csproj format

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to use the new csproj format in VisualStudio 2017 but the Debug tab miss the `Use remote machine` option.

The VisualStudio 2017 debug tab with the old csproj format:

[image]

We can easy to use this to remote debug.

But we can not find the option in VisualStudio 2017 with the new csproj format.

[image]

How can we use remote debug in VisualStudio 2017 with new csproj format?

And I do not want to use attach to process and set the connection target to remote debug that is inefficient.

[image]

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017

[Remote debugging - Visual Studio | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging?view=vs-2017)

Comment: Thank for @Zulander But I do not want to use attach to process and set the connection target to remote debug that is inefficient.

Comment: Thx for @BACON it is duplicate.